# How can I update labels and UIImage placeholder from local JSON?

Tags: json, swift

So I have a JSON file that I need to parse and update labels and image. In my storyboard I have 4 labels (image of an animal, region, it's weight and length) and uiimage where I need to put it's picture. 
I need to update labels and image by parsing JSON.
This is how far I was able to get to...

My JSON look like this:

```
"data":[
     {
         "name":"Lion",
         "thumbnail":"https://kopelion.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Kimani.jpg",
         "region":"Africa",
         "stats":{
            "max_weight":180,
            "length":250
         }
      }
]
```

I tried to get into this by writing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json") else { return }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
            print(json)

            guard let array = json as? [Any] else { return }

            for animal in array {
                guard let animalDict = animal as? [String: Any] else { return }
                guard let animalName = animalDict["name"] as? String else { return }
                guard let animalRegion = animalDict["region"] as? String else { return }
                guard let animalStats = animalDict["stats"] as? String else { return }

                print(animalName)
                print(animalRegion)
                print(animalStats)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please spend a little time learning how Stack Overflow formatting works. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please abandon JSONSerialization and use JSONDecoder with Decodable structs.

Comment: Ok, but could you explain what exactly should I do in this situation?

Comment: And thanks for that link about formatting! I'll read it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, most of the times the main culprit is `json` file itself, as in your case.

You need to `fix` the `json` code first, by `adding "{" at the top` and `"}" at the bottom` of your `json` file's code.

This will make it `valid json`

And then `do the following`

Replace your code lines:

```
// 1
guard let array = json as? [Any] else { return }

// 2
guard let animalStats = animalDict["stats"] as? String else { return }
```

with this:

```
// 1
guard let dictionary = json as? [String:[Any]] else { return }
guard let array = dictionary["data"]  else { return }

//2
guard let animalRegion = animalDict["region"] as? String else { return }
```

> Quik tip : 1. Check your json using online tools like https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer
>
> 2. Try to use JSONDecoder and JSONEncoder instead of JSONSerialization

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have properties in your class for the storyboard items you want to set. e.g.,:

```
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel! // outside functions but inside class, and hooked up in Storyboard

// inside viewDidLoad

name.text = animalDict["name"] as? String
```

I wouldn't bother with the intermediate variables unless you really need them.

Answer (score 0):

As you are responsible for the JSON delete the enclosing dictionary `data`, it's not needed.

```
[{
   "name":"Lion",
   "thumbnail":"https://kopelion.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Kimani.jpg",
   "region":"Africa",
   "stats":{
      "max_weight":180,
      "length":250
   }
}]
```

Create two structs

```
struct Animal: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let thumbnail: URL
    let region: String
    let stats: Stats
}

struct Stats: Decodable {
    let maxWeight, length: Int
}
```

In the view controller declare a data source array

```
var animals = [Animal]()
```

In `viewDidLoad` parse the data with `JSONDecoder` and assign the result to the data source array

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    self.animals = try! decoder.decode([Animal].self, from: data)
}
```

All `guard`s and `try`s are actually not needed. The file must exist at compile time and cannot be modified at runtime so the code must not crash.

You can get the animal *properties* with

```
let animal = animals[0]
let name = animal.name
let weight = animal.stats.weight
print(name, weight)
```

Assuming there are more animals in the JSON use a loop

```
for animal in animals {
    let name = animal.name
    let weight = animal.stats.weight
    print(name, weight)
}
```

How to update the labels is unclear because there is no significant information about the design in your question.

To get the image load it asynchronously with `URLSession`

Comment: Hey Vadian! Thank you so much for this answer! It looks pretty legit and I believe it should work. I'm trying to implement this right now, but there is one mistake that concerns me in this line

    let url = url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")!

Xcode complains that "Variable used within its own initial value"
Please advice..